# Why does this dereference to file_operations happen this way?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, vfs

I am referencing [this](https://yassine.tioual.com/posts/hiding-processes-for-fun-and-profit/) article and I am confused about this bit of code here:

```
    /* get a copy of file_operations from inode */
    proc_fops = *proc_inode->i_fop;
    /* backup the file_operations */
    backup_proc_fops = proc_inode->i_fop;
```

`file_operations` is a struct (stores vfs functions) and `proc_inode` would be pointing to the inode file_operations (`i_fop`). Why would he deference that again? Why not use the same as the `backup_proc_fops` code?

References to structs:

- [`struct file_operations`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1821)
- [`struct inode`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L628)
- [`i_fop` field in `struct inode`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L709)

Comment: It's the same as `*(proc_inode->i_fop)`. Dereferencing the member `i_fop`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne What's the difference in the value? I assume backup_proc_fops stores the address of the i_fop, so does proc_fops give you access to the struct itself?

Comment: Yes. `proc_fops` is, as mentioned in the source code comment, a copy. `backup_proc_fops` is a pointer to the object being copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `i_fop` is a *pointer to* `struct file_operations`, if you want to *copy* the struct that it is pointing, you need to dereference it.

This:

```
struct file_operations proc_fops;
proc_fops = *proc_inode->i_fop;
```

Will copy the entire `struct file_operations` pointed by `i_fop`. In other words, it's an entire struct initialized from the fields of `i_fop`. It's the same as doing the following:

```
struct mystruct { /*...*/ };

struct mystruct *ptr;
struct mystruct copy;

ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
// ...

copy = *ptr;
```

On the other hand, this:

```
backup_proc_fops = proc_inode->i_fop;
```

Only copies the *pointer* to the `struct file_operations`, and not its content. It's the same as doing the following (continuing from the above example):

```
struct mystruct *another_ptr;
another_ptr = ptr;
```

---

In the link you reference, all of this is done because `proc_fops` will be *modified* and then used to replace the original `i_fop` pointer in `proc_inode`:

```
/* modify the copy with out evil function */
proc_fops.iterate_shared = rk_iterate_shared;
/* overwrite the proc entry's file_operations */
proc_inode->i_fop = &proc_fops;
```

While `backup_proc_fops` will just keep the original pointer to be restored later when the module is unloaded:

```
/* get inode and restore file_operations */
proc_inode = p.dentry->d_inode;
proc_inode->i_fop = backup_proc_fops;
```

---

Instead of all this, one could have done:

```
proc_inode->i_fop->iterate_shared = rk_iterate_shared;
```

**but** that would have modified the original struct, making the change irreversible.